# What does this modal verb mean?

Tags: modal-verbs

> "The forest?" he repeated, and he didn't sound quite as cool as
>   usual. "We can't go in there at night –– there's all sorts of things
>   in there –– werewolves, I heard." 
>       Neville clutched the sleeve of Harry's robe and made a choking noise. 
>       "That's your problem, isn't it?" said Filch, his voice cracking with glee. "Should've thought of them werewolves before you got in
>   trouble, shouldn't you?" 
>       Hagrid came striding toward them out of the dark, Fang [his dog] at his heel. He was carrying his large crossbow, and a quiver of
>   arrows hung over his shoulder. 
>       "Abou' time," he said. "I bin waitin' fer half an hour already. All right, Harry, Hermione?" 
>       "I **shouldn't** be too friendly to them, Hagrid," said Filch coldly, they're here to be punished, after all." 
>       "That's why yer late, is it?" said Hagrid, frowning at Filch. "Bin lecturin' them, eh? 'Snot your place ter do that. Yeh've done yer bit,
>   I'll take over from here." 
>       "I'll be back at dawn," said Filch, "for what's left of them," he added nastily, and he turned and started back toward the castle, his
>   lamp bobbing away in the darkness. 
>  (Harry Potter and the
>   Sorcerer's Stone)

What does the ‘should’ mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a slightly dated idiomatic usage with overtones of "pseudo-formality". More naturally, Filch could say...

> *I **wouldn't** be too friendly to them [if I were you]*.

And more logically/grammatically, he could say...

> ***You shouldn't** be too friendly to them*.

...but he avoids that because it might be perceived as "permemptorily rude".

---

Regarding the "overtones", I think most native speakers would be influenced by the fact that...

> *I **should** like you to leave now*

...is generally considered somewhat formal/starchy/stilted/dated phrasing, compared to

> *I **would** like you to leave now*

...which itself is just "polite circumlocution" for...

> *I **want** you to leave now*

Comment: I don't get the overtones at all. I think it just has its ordinary meaning, "I shouldn't [do X]" just means that it would be improper for me to do X.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz FumbleFingers is speaking of British usage, which retains in many speech communities the old-fashioned use of *shall/should* instead of *will/would* in the first person. Since the Harry Potter books are set in England, and Filch is an elderly speaker, I think FumbleFingers is correct.

Comment: @David: I wasn't aware of StoneyB's point that *I shouldn't [do something]* is a particularly ***British*** usage, but on purely semantic grounds I can't see how you can avoid interpreting ***I*** there as meaning ***you***. What possible reason could Filch have for telling Hagrid that it would be "improper" for ***him*** (Filch) to be over-friendly towards the children? After all, presumably Filch himself hasn't been at all friendly, and he's saying this immediately after Hagrid *has* been.